# Transmitting data to functions in JSX loops: scoped functions vs data attributes

Tags: reactjs

I had a long discussion with a coworker to decide between two (or three) concepts when sending data (like an ID or key) to a function. My question is more about (memory)performance as about syntactic sugar.

Consider this little app:

```
export default class Untitled extends Component { 
  state = { todos: ["first todo", "second todo", "third todo"] } 

  deleteTodo(???) { 
    // some array slice to remove a todo 
  }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <ul> 
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => 
            <li key={index}>{todo} <a onClick={ ??? }>delete</a> 
         </li>
        } 
      </ul> 
    ) 
  } 
}
```

How do you get the id from the todo which the user clicked to the `deleteTodo()` method in the most efficient way? I can think of three ways:

First:

`<li key={index}>{todo} <a onClick={ () => { this.deleteTodo(index) } }>delete</a></li>`

Second:

```
deleteTodo(id) {
  return ()=>{
     // some array slice to remove a todo
  }
}

<li key={index}>{todo} <a onClick={  this.deleteTodo(index)  }>delete</a></li>
```

Third:

```
deleteTodo(event) {
  const { id } = event.currentTarget.dataset
  // some array slice to remove a todo
}
<li key={index}>{todo} <a data-id={index} onClick={  this.deleteTodo  }>delete</a></li>
```

What is the best of these three options, and why? I always used method one (should be basically equal to method two in terms of performance), but after the discussion, I started to question myself if method three is more performant because it does not create so many function instances for each render call?

I tried to research a bit on this topic, but I haven't found any in-depth comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The whole argument is basically that inline functions are bad cos they're re-created on every render and lead to unnecessary re-rendering of children. While that's technically true, I've never had that cause performance issues. It's basically just if you have an element that simultaneously renders hundreds of children (and if the children are re-rendered frequently, that exacerbates it).

In general you shouldn't be rendering hundreds or thousands of things at the same time, cos even without inline functions that's not performant. Better to do something like paginate the data. However if you did, then something like the third approach where you create a single, bound function in the parent and pass it to the children would be better in terms of performance. Since in that case, even when the parent re-renders, the function that all the children's `onClick` is referencing hasn't changed, so they won't re-render (assuming none of their other props change too).

On a side note, don't use the `index` as the key, that will cause buggy behaviour when you add/delete items. React won't be able to track updates to the list properly. If the list is going to be edited, each item needs a unique identifier as its key.

In short, you *can* use inlined functions unless you're certain that you'll be rendering lots and lots of children and/or the children will be re-rendered very often. If you Google "react inline function" or things like that you can find plenty of articles on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to pass the parameter `index` to `deleteTodo`, you need to call it like this `()=>this.deleteTodo(index)`
you should use an arrow function `()=>` otherwise it will be running at the same time with the `render()` function
So the first solution is correct and the others are wrong

Comment: You are talking about the second option?
`deleteTodo(id)` scopes the id and returns a function, so no need to use another arrow function at this approach :) all three approaches work as they are presented. I just want to know which one has the best performance.